# Indexing error when using step

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import os
read_path = "/home/tanvir/test/"

startFile = 1   #first file in the folder
endFile = 1000  #last file considered
freqMeas = 0.5
step = 1 if endFile <= 500 else 8
time = [freqMeas * (x + 1) for x in range(startFile, endFile + 1, step)]
Nt = np.size(time)
execfile(read_path + str(startFile) + ".py")
ndimz = np.size(phiPart)
phiPart_t = np.zeros((ndimz, Nt))

k = startFile
for k in range(startFile, endFile + 1, step):
    execfile(read_path + str(k) + ".py")
    phiPart_t[:,k] = phiPart2[:] / (phiPart[:] + 1e-6)
```

When my step is 1 this code is running fine but when my step is 8, it is giving me IndexError: index 128 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 126. I need to read every 10th instead of every file if my endfile is larger than 500.

Comment: Your example cannot be run without the related files. Please consider making a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: in each .py files there is 1d array of phipart 2=[1,2,3,4..525] and phipart=[1,2,3,4...525]